# How to make an animation of sequential arrays with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a beginner in python. My problem is an interaction between two cars that have to cross an simple intersection. I've already obtained the answer I need in a language called FIACRE. In this language I've implemented a grid 6 x 6 like this:

```
a= [[1,1,1,1,1,1], 
    [1,1,0,2,1,1],
    [1,3,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,1,0,0,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

Where the 1's represent the sidewalks, 0's are the streets, and 2 and 3 are the cars. I've obtained a list of results like this: m1, m2, m3, m4, m5 and m6. Each one represent a kind of movement.

```
#(m,n) and (y,x) are the coordinates for each car
# this is how I implemented in FIACRE, not in python
m1: if  a[y][x]=2 and a[y][x-1]=0; then a[y][x-1]:=2; a[y][x]:=0; x:=x-1;
m2: if  a[y][x]=2 and a[y+1][x]=0; then a[y+1][x]:=2; a[y][x]:=0; y:=y+1;
m3: if  a[y][x]=2 and a[y][x+1]=0; then a[y][x+1]:=2; a[y][x]:=0; x:=x+1; 
m4: if  a[m][n]=3 and a[m][n+1]=0; then a[m][n+1]:=3; a[m][n]:=0; n:=n+1;
m5: if  a[m][n]=3 and a[m-1][n]=0; then a[m-1][n]:=3; a[m][n]:=0; m:=m-1;
m6: if  a[m][n]=3 and a[m+1][n]=0; then a[m+1][n]:=3; a[m][n]:=0; m:=m+1;
```

I've started to implement a python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# here I import the .txt file with the m steps obtained in FIACRE
steps = pd.read_table("C:\\Users\\...\\ file.txt")

nrows, ncols = 6,6 #number of rows and columns

# Make a 6x6 grid...
image = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1],
                  [1,1,0,3,1,1],
                  [1,2,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,1,0,0,1,1],
                  [1,1,1,1,1,1]])

plt.matshow(image)
plt.show()
```

What I expected is a code that implements the steps that I have to change the array (image). Then, animate the arrays obtained in each step to simulate the car movements, and save in a gif.

Comment: It may not be too clear what the problem is. The Python syntax for the first line would be `if  (a[y][x]==2 and a[y][x-1]==0): a[y][x-1]=2; a[y][x]=0; x=x-1` (a new line needs to come after the `:`).

Comment: Oh. This part is how I implemented in the other language.

Comment: Yes, so I provided you with the same but in python, because as I understand, that is your question.

Comment: Yeah. But now, how  I iterate my array in order to change the coordinates of '2' and '3' elements and then save each transformation in the array to animate it? As each change is a frame in a movie

Comment: You can look at matplotlib's `FuncAnimation`.